# Property of 'java.util.NavigableMap' type cannot be injected by 'Map'

Tags: java, spring, dictionary

I have code from my `spring-config.xml`

```
<property name="auditoriums">
     <map>
          <entry key-ref="first_event_dateTime" value-ref="auditorium_1" />
     </map>
</property>
```

And code in `Event.java`:

```
public void setAuditoriums(NavigableMap<LocalDateTime, Auditorium> auditoriums) {
    this.auditoriums = auditoriums;
}
```

I catch exception

> org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required
>   type 'java.util.NavigableMap'

Help, me, please, to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either set targetMapClass property of [MapFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MapFactoryBean.html) or use something like

```
<util:map map-class="java.util.TreeMap">
```

You can find some examples here: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-mapfactorybean-example/